# Sort List<object> by nested List<object> property

Tags: c#, list, sorting, object, nested

I have a list of objects that is added to another list of objects.
**How do I sort the list by a property in the sub list of objects?**
See SUDO code below. Any Help would be really appreciated. C#

```
List<object> MainListOfObject = new List<object>();
List<object> subListObject_0 = new List<object>();
List<object> subListObject_1 = new List<object>();
List<object> subListObject_2 = new List<object>();
    
cat_a = {Age: 3, Colour: "white"}
cat_b = {Age: 2, Colour: "black"}
cat_c = {Age: 2.5, Colour: "black & white"}

dog_a = {Height: 0.5, EyeColour: "green"}
dog_b = {Height: 0.6, EyeColour: "blue"} 
dog_c = {Height: 0.2, EyeColour: "brown"}
  
Console.WriteLine(cat_a.Age); //output 1
Console.WriteLine(cat_b.Colour); //output "black"

   
subListObject_0.Add(cat_a);
subListObject_0.Add(dog_a);

subListObject_1.Add(cat_b);
subListObject_1.Add(dog_b);

subListObject_2.Add(cat_c);
subListObject_2.Add(dog_c);

    
MainListOfObject.Add(subListObject_0);
MainListOfObject.Add(subListObject_1);
MainListOfObject.Add(subListObject_2);

//How do I sort MainListOfObject by nested object property Age?
```

????? MainListOfObject.OrderBy(o[0] => o[0].Age).ToList(); ?????

```
Console.WriteLine(MainListOfObject[0][0].Age); //output 2
Console.WriteLine(MainListOfObject[1][0].Age); //output 2.5
Console.WriteLine(MainListOfObject[2][0].Age); //output 3
```

Comment: Why not make an Animal base class and have age as a property?

Comment: Like Nick suggests you probably want to look at some polymorphism here. Take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism) to see how it works if you haven't worked much with class inheritance yet.

Comment: MainListOfObject.OrderBy(sub => sub.Min(cat => cat.Age)); (I assume your real code is with real classes, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just define actual types for your animals. Your example uses anonymous types and objects, and that is just not the way to write c# code.

To define the animals we can use [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) for a compact way to define a simple type. But a class or struct would work just as well, it would just be a bit more code to write.

To represent a combination of types it is sometimes appropriate to use [Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), since this support an nice compact syntax:

```
public record Cat(int Age, string Color);
public record Dog(float Height, string EyeColor);
...
var mainListOfObject = new List<(Cat cat, Dog dog)>();
mainListOfObject.Add((new Cat(3, "white"), new Dog(0.5f,  "green")));
var sortedList = mainListOfObject.OrderBy(p => p.cat.Age).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the information I could not use records as I am using .net 4, however I could use tuples. var mainListOfObject = new List<Tuple<cat, dog>>();  var sortedList = mainListOfObject .OrderBy(p => p.Item1.Age).ToList();

Comment: @Alastair, you can still use records and valuetuple syntax in .Net framework, at least on .net 4.8 (and you should really update if you are using an older version), but you need some project settings to make it work.